# Trouble with schema using pyarrow.parquet ParquetDataset (how to force a particular schema)

Tags: python, python-3.x, parquet, pyarrow

Let's explain the context:
Someone gives me multiple parquet files obtain from multiple .csv files. I want to read all this parquet files and make a big dataset. For this I use pyarrow.parquet package.

So, I have multiple parquet file (We could call them file1.pq ; file2.pq ; file3.pq). All the files have exactly the same structure: the same column name and the same content of column. But sometimes in all the rows of a column in one file the value is the same and egal to NA. In this particular case the function `dataset = pq.ParquetDataset(file_list)` fail because physical type change.

lets make a visual exemple:

```
| File1.csv              |
|-------------|-----|----|
| Column Name | C1  | C2 |
|-------------|-----|----|
| Row 1       | YES | 10 |
| Row 2       | NA  | 15 |
| Row 3       | NO  | 9  |

| File2.csv              |
|-------------|-----|----|
| Column Name | C1  | C2 |
|-------------|-----|----|
| Row 1       | NA  | 10 |
| Row 2       | NA  | 15 |
| Row 3       | NA  | 9  |

| File2.csv              |
|-------------|-----|----|
| Column Name | C1  | C2 |
|-------------|-----|----|
| Row 1       | YES | 10 |
| Row 2       | NA  | 15 |
| Row 3       | NO  | 9  |
```

After conversion to parquet we have:

```
pq.ParquetFile("File1.pq").schema[1].physical_type = 'BYTE_ARRAY' --> good !
pq.ParquetFile("File1.pq").schema[2].physical_type = 'DOUBLE' --> good !

pq.ParquetFile("File2.pq").schema[1].physical_type = 'DOUBLE' --> BAD !
pq.ParquetFile("File2.pq").schema[2].physical_type = 'DOUBLE' --> good !

pq.ParquetFile("File3.pq").schema[1].physical_type = 'BYRE_ARRAY' --> good!
pq.ParquetFile("File3.pq").schema[2].physical_type = 'DOUBLE' --> good !
```

I try to open each parquet file and modify column type with something like that :

```
for i in  np.arange(0,len(file_list)):

    if list_have_to_change[i] != []:

        df = pd.read_parquet(file_list[i])

        df[list_have_to_change[i]] = df[list_have_to_change[i]].astype(bytearray)

        df.to_parquet(COPIEPATH + "\\" + ntpath.basename(file_list[i]))

    else :

        shutil.move(file_list[i],COPIEPATH + "\\" + ntpath.basename(file_list[i]))
```

Where:

`file_list` contain all the parquet file

`list_have_to_change` is a list of a list of column name whose the name has to be change. In our example it was `[[],[C1],[]]`.

But after `to_parquet()` methode schema return

```
BYTE_ARRAY for 1;

DOUBLE for 2;

BYTE_ARRAY for 3;
```

So it's change anything.

***Question: How can I force schema when I save into parquet file or how can I use pq.ParquetDataset(file_list) with non coherent physical type ?***

Hope that I was clear, thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Apparently you can pass a metadata instance right to the `ParquetDataset` constructor. Could it help read the columns in the right format?

Comment: My understanding of this parameter is: ParquetDataset Will check if metadata passed is the same as metadata of de Data contain in files. What Di you think about that ?

Comment: IDK; I only used Parquet with Spark, and there you can pass an explicit schema everywhere you load or store something; the interface is different.